# No such Element exception for matrix of integers?

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

Though my code seems to be very small and simple but it is throwing No Such element exception..The question is we take a matrix of integers and we should check if there are elements around which all elements are less than that element. And we have to replace that element with 'X'.No need to check border elements... Actually I am new to java...so any corrections are appreciated!!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= in.nextInt();
    int a[][] = new int[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) //getting input from user
        {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
            a[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) // checking the condition
        {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
            if(i!=0 && i!=n-1 && j!=0 && j!=n-1)
                {
                if(a[i-1][j]<a[i][j] && a[i+1][j]<a[i][j] && a[i][j-1]<a[i][j] && a[i][j+1]<a[i][j])
                    {
                    System.out.println("X ");
                }
                else
                    {
                    System.out.println(a[i][j]+" ");
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}

input:           output:
4                 
1112              1112    
1912              1X12
1892              18X2 
1234              1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition `if(i!=0 && i!=n-1 && j!=0 && j!=n-1)` should be changed to...

```
if(i>0 && i<n-1 && j>0 && j<n-1)
```

and you will be fine. Try to resolve that the index of arrays do not exceed the limit, which in this case happens when `a[i+1][j]<a[i][j]` or `a[i][j+1]<a[i][j]` is called.

Comment: the exception is on the eighteenth line...that is on a[i][j]= in.nextInt() line

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution a `StringBuilder` without difficult tests :

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to test?");
    int x = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++){
        sb.append(in.nextLine()).append(" ");
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < sb.toString().length() ; i++){
        if (Character.getNumericValue(sb.toString().charAt(i)) > n){
            sb.replace(i, i+1, "X");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());

    }
}
```

---

**Output**

```
5
How many numbers do you want to test?
2
123456789
999555444
12345XXXX XXX555444
```